# Global session variable in express.js route?

Tags: session, express

when i set a session in express.js route like

```
app.get('/', function(req, res() {
req.session.foo = 'bar';
});
```

i can't access it (undefined) in other routes. is this possible? is there a special configuration i have to consider?

thanks!

Comment: Can you post your app configuration?

Comment: Most probably you didn't used
`app.use(express.cookieParser())
app.use(express.session({secret: '123'}))`

Answer (score 1):

i actually solved it by just setting the sessions like this:

```
global.session.email = JSON.parse(chunk).email;
```

through this, the session variables are global!

**solved**!

Comment: Where is global defined?