# Making Session Data Accessible From Everywhere (In An Express.js Project)

Tags: session, express, coffeescript

I am using **Express-Middleware** in an **outsourced file**.

I set some session data in that outsourced file:

```
req.session.userId
```

Now I want to access this variable in my **root file** (app.js), but there it is **NULL**.

How can I make this session data *accessible* from everywhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900622/global-session-variable-in-express-js-route This is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. You simply declare the variable as global:

**./app.js**

```
global.session = { }
```

Now you can reach this object from everywhere:

```
global.session.userId = 1
```

As seen here:

[Global session variable in express.js route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900622/global-session-variable-in-express-js-route)